# How do I correctly define a constant variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I had to do a stand reminder in JS, but I have a problem, I've a const which is note defined and I don't know why, I tried to understand why with `console.log()`
My code is :

```
    const q = require('daskeyboard-applet');
const logger = q.logger; // to access to the logger


class StandReminder extends q.DesktopApp {
  // this method run () return a signal object
  //we need to sent a signal here
  async run() {
    logger.info("Running.");
    const reminder = this.config.reminder;

    //I take the content of the JSON file with config    
    var counter = 0;
    const color = '#00FF00';
    console.log("the reminder is ", reminder);

    if (counter >= reminder) {
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else {
      return new q.Signal({
        points: [
          [new q.Point(color)]
        ],
        name: 'Stand Reminder',
        message: `${reminder}` //il prend bien la meme valeur que reminder
      })
    }
  }
}


module.exports = {
  StandReminder: StandReminder
}


const applet = new StandReminder();
```

The problem is on the following line

```
const reminder = this.config.reminder;
```

I code a test.js in order to test my code on the terminal with `yarn test`, the code is :

```
  describe('#run()', () => {
    it('sends a reminder from 30', async function () {
      let app = new StandReminder();
      let reminder = 30;
      app.config.reminder = reminder;

      return app.run().then((signal) => {
        console.log(signal); passe jusque la
        assert.ok(signal); 
        console.log(signal.message);
        assert(signal.message.includes(reminder));
        assert(signal.name.includes('Stand Reminder'));
      }).catch((error) => {
        assert.fail(error)
      });
    })
  });  
})
```

So I tried to test if I have a good code but when I test the code on the terminal I have the reminder undefined and I don't know why can you help me please?

Comment: Why is your method async? Do you know about the async-await-syntax?

Comment: It's a matter of scope; `reminder`is inside a block; it's not global.

Comment: ok so what can I do please ? @Haroldo_OK

Comment: have you got a solution for me please ? @Haroldo_OK